# Returning an empty JSON array causing out of bounds error in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I'm accessing a JSON array in Swift:

```
genres: [
{
id: 6,
title: "Comedy"
}
],
```

I'm using the code:

```
     if let genreInfo = jsonResult["genres"]?[0] as? [String: AnyObject]{
        let genre = genreInfo["title"] as? String
        genreArray.append(genre)
}
```

which works if a genre is present but if the genre JSON data is [  ], I get an array out of bounds error. Is there a way to refactor it so it doesn't cause an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are assuming that, if the array exists then it has at least one value. And this causes your issue.

Try this

```
if let genreInfo = jsonResult["genres"]?.first as? [String: AnyObject] {
    let genre = genreInfo["title"] as? String
    genreArray.append(genre)
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code, it throws the error: "Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member first".

Comment: @tylerD: Maybe you changed it to `firstObject`? In this case that's why you have a `NSArray`, not a native Swift array.